# MongoDB connections are failing with "SocketException... SEND_ERROR"

Tags: mongodb

I have a production MongoDB 2.4 that's giving this error in the logs:

```
SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:37934]
```

The client's logs report a connection timeout.

`mongod --version` reports v2.4.10 (I'm on Debian jessie; MongoDB is installed from the jessie repositories) and the `net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time` sysctl is set to 300 as recommended by [SocketException in Mongo logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/427371/socketexception-in-mongo-logs?answertab=votes#tab-top). Also, the error is still present when triggering a database query directly after restarting MongoDB and the application, which to me suggests that this is not SERVER-5632 (mentioned in the above question).

`/proc/pid/limits` reports unlimited for everything except stack size, core file size, processes, locked memory, pending signals, msgqueue size, nice and realtime priority, and open files. This last one in particular has a soft limit of 1024 and a hard limit of 4096, which isn't what the MongoDB docs recommend but shouldn't be a problem anyway since  `ls /proc/pid/fd | wc -l` reports only 29 open fds.

`free -g` reports 3 GB of free memory, +/- buffers and cache. Rebooting the entire server seems to help *somewhat* for a short time, but then it gets just as bad again. Here's a snippet from the log:

```
Wed Mar  1 20:14:17.466 [conn1]  authenticate db: pumpio { authenticate: 1, user: "pump.io", nonce: "7ac439ffd4c01a6d", key: "abe7862c7eb1f9765ebaa007d7c20ec2" }
Wed Mar  1 20:14:26.445 [conn1] command pumpio.$cmd command: { authenticate: 1, user: "pump.io", nonce: "7ac439ffd4c01a6d", key: "abe7862c7eb1f9765ebaa007d7c20ec2" } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) W:8978364 r:412 reslen:74 8979ms
Wed Mar  1 20:14:41.809 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58216 #2 (2 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:46.302 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58218 #3 (3 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:49.212 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58220 #4 (4 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:49.212 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58222 #5 (5 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:49.212 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58224 #6 (6 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:49.213 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58226 #7 (7 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:49.213 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58228 #8 (8 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:49.213 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58230 #9 (9 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:49.213 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58232 #10 (10 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:49.213 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58234 #11 (11 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:49.213 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58236 #12 (12 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:50.685 [conn1] query pumpio.session query: { _id: "9n_7gseqgT8i07tQbnBj7gNgURdQNmS8" } ntoreturn:1 idhack:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:13911898 reslen:202 17129ms
Wed Mar  1 20:14:50.695 [conn2]  authenticate db: pumpio { authenticate: 1, user: "pump.io", nonce: "7e918deb40e23f92", key: "0b4b2d78fa404e594dc1d066c9402cc4" }
Wed Mar  1 20:14:52.960 [conn1] SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:58214]
Wed Mar  1 20:14:52.960 [conn7] assertion 16550 not authorized for query on reportr.system.indexes ns:reportr.system.indexes query:{ ns: "reportr.alerts" }
Wed Mar  1 20:14:52.960 [conn12] assertion 16550 not authorized for query on reportr.system.indexes ns:reportr.system.indexes query:{ ns: "reportr.alerts" }
Wed Mar  1 20:14:52.960 [conn5] assertion 16550 not authorized for query on reportr.system.indexes ns:reportr.system.indexes query:{ ns: "reportr.events" }
Wed Mar  1 20:14:52.960 [conn10] assertion 16550 not authorized for query on reportr.system.indexes ns:reportr.system.indexes query:{ ns: "reportr.events" }
Wed Mar  1 20:14:58.713 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58238 #13 (12 connections now open)
Wed Mar  1 20:14:58.715 [conn13]  authenticate db: pumpio { authenticate: 1, user: "pump.io", nonce: "fe508e5612e933fa", key: "492c9d11f582c045941da7f7eb16b8bd" }
Wed Mar  1 20:15:07.599 [conn2] update pumpio.session query: { _id: "i_vJ67QJA56LsQvLMF8GuiosMHUj7--P" } update: { cookie: { originalMaxAge: null, expires: null, httpOnly: true, path: "/" }, _id: "i_vJ67QJA56LsQvLMF8GuiosMHUj7--P" } idhack:1 nupdated:1 upsert:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:16896964 16897ms
Wed Mar  1 20:15:07.600 [conn2] SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:58216]
Wed Mar  1 20:15:07.600 [conn13] command pumpio.$cmd command: { authenticate: 1, user: "pump.io", nonce: "fe508e5612e933fa", key: "492c9d11f582c045941da7f7eb16b8bd" } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:1225 reslen:74 8885ms
Wed Mar  1 20:15:08.050 [conn13] update pumpio.session query: { _id: "deiIhAPc1vaXYZ_JzU72slghiCMOu1Zf" } update: { cookie: { originalMaxAge: null, expires: null, httpOnly: true, path: "/" }, _id: "deiIhAPc1vaXYZ_JzU72slghiCMOu1Zf" } idhack:1 nupdated:1 upsert:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:109 447ms
Wed Mar  1 20:15:15.592 [TTLMonitor] query local.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:142680 nreturned:0 reslen:20 142ms
Wed Mar  1 20:15:30.773 [conn13] query pumpio.recentdialbackrequests query: { _id: 0 } ntoreturn:1 idhack:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:2751358 reslen:95317 2751ms
Wed Mar  1 20:16:14.855 [conn13] query pumpio.comment query: { _uuid: "oudHqMliREq5HSXd-7N62Q" } ntoreturn:1000 ntoskip:0 nscanned:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:3247907 nreturned:1 reslen:900 4951ms
Wed Mar  1 20:16:14.855 [conn13] SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:58238]
```

This is right after I rebooted the MongoDB server and the application server. Both of these are on the same host and the application connects to `localhost` to issue database queries.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have a look into this: http://serverfault.com/questions/427371/socketexception-in-mongo-logs

Comment: @anand I've seen that question. in fact, it's linked in _my_ question. so you may safely assume that I read it and it didn't help.